# Can there be a feature for moderators to "reject" a question migration?

Tags: feature-request, migration, moderator-abilities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow diamond moderators to reverse question migrations?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35744/allow-diamond-moderators-to-reverse-question-migrations)

This question is similar in spirit to [this previous one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73391/require-migrated-questions-to-be-accepted-by-the-destination-sites-moderators) which asked whether it is possible to require migrated questions to be accepted by the destination site's moderators. If what is described in that question is not completely feasible, would it be possible for a mechanism to exist to allow the moderator to reject a migration *post de facto* and kick it back to the originating site?

---

A [case in point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16062/how-to-plot-polar-function-onto-cartesian-grid) (on Math.SE for which I am a moderator) is a question migrated from Stack Overflow to Math.StackExchange. Looking at the comments it is pretty clear that the original poster, several high-reputation users at Math.SE, and some moderators disagree with the migration of the question. In fact, given that the question actually asked and the example solutions provided to the question, the question really much better belongs on Stack Overflow than on Math.StackExchange (being a programming one rather than a math one).

An especially unfortunate side-effect of the migration was that the question picked up some down-votes because *it was migrated to the wrong forum and thus is now off-topic*.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73391/require-migrated-questions-to-be-accepted-by-the-destination-sites-moderators

Comment: Duplicate of [Allow diamond moderators to reverse question migrations?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35744/allow-diamond-moderators-to-reverse-question-migrations)

Answer (score 3):

You can essentially already do this. Close/delete it on Math, and mod flag the original post telling them what happened, and an SO mod can clear the migration history on the SO side